# Binary Search Tree, Search method

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to run my `Binary Search Tree`, I am creating objects of type `Employee` in my main program which does not seem to give me problems, but when I choose to search for an item in my `BST`, the program is terminated.

```
 System.out.println("Searching the Binary Search Tree");
                        System.out.println("Enter surname to search for:");
                        String choice2 = sc.nextLine(); 
                        BinaryNode a = temp.search(choice2);
                        Employee newEmp = (Employee) a.obj;
                        if (a == null)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Not Found");
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                System.out.println(newEmp.getData());
                            }
                       break;
                    }
```

When the program terminates, it points to the line

```
Employee newEmp = (Employee) a.obj;
```

and the error given is, `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

Could anyone tell me why this is happening please?

Comment: Because `temp.search(choice2);` returns `null`?

Comment: I showed my search method, is it ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access to .obj of null object.
Line should be moved after check whether a==null.

```
 System.out.println("Searching the Binary Search Tree");
                    System.out.println("Enter surname to search for:");
                    String choice2 = sc.nextLine(); 
                    BinaryNode a = temp.search(choice2);
                    if (a == null)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Not Found");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            Employee newEmp = (Employee) a.obj;
                            System.out.println(newEmp.getData());
                        }
                   break;
                }
```

Comment: Oh this makes sense, now I've gotten another problem, when I run the program, the program is skipping the part where I input a surname, could this be because of my sc.nextLine()? was not sure about it

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if the temp.search(choice2) is return a non-null value? casts with null references results in such errors

In addition to it make sure that the cast you are performing for the BinaryNode a is indeed Employee. (though this is not related to the NullPointerException)

Comment: It's not the cast which results in the error, it's the member access. Casting `null` to any object type works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `search` method can return `null`, so you should reorganize your code and add line `Employee newEmp = (Employee) a.obj;` to `else` part of condition.

Comment: Oh this makes sense, now I've gotten another problem, when I run the program, the program is skipping the part where I input a surname, could this be because of my sc.nextLine()? was not sure about it